# Content scraping

Tags: discussion, copyright

I noticed recently that a [YouTube user](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPF-oYb2-xN5FbCXy0167Gg) is scraping Ask Ubuntu (and possibly other stackexchange sites) and posting videos with the questions and answers. A few examples:

**My wireless is hard-blocked**

Ask Ubuntu question - [My wireless is hard-blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155391/my-wireless-is-hard-blocked)

Scraped video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIhq2kJKp1M

**How to avoid "Assuming drive cache: write through" message during restart?**

Ask Ubuntu question - [How to avoid "Assuming drive cache: write through" message during restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32107/how-to-avoid-assuming-drive-cache-write-through-message-during-restart)

Scraped video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5TvNXOkgJ4

I don't know if content on this website is licenced under Creative Commons, but I think this action is worrying as he's also linking to a Patreon to get money out of people. Should this behaviour be stopped? Can it be stopped?

Comment: I reported him to Patreon but he doesn't make any money anyway and I doubt anyone is going to support such half-arsed content as that.

Comment: A _video_ of a text based question? Sigh. The world has gone mad.

Comment: Be aware, that content on this site is CC-BY-SA 4.0 - in the Video's description they cite the sources. There isn't really a conflict of license here (in this case)